# jQuery - Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with my validation process. I'm not using a standard "submit" button, rather I have `<span class="button" id="print">Print</span>` and jQuery listens for a click. This is the validation code I have when that "button" is clicked:

```
var validation = "";
function validate() {
  $("#servDetails").find("input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("required") && $(this).val() == "") {
      validation = false;
      }
    else {
      validation = true;
      }
    });

  $("#checklist").find("input[required]").each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("required") && $(this).val() == "") {
      validation = false;
      }
    else {
      validation = true;
      }
    });
  }

$("#print").on("click", function() {
  validate();

  if (validation == false) {
    alert("Please fill out all required inputs!");
    return false;
    }
  else {
    window.print();
    }
  });
```

If I click the button without filling anything out (all items blank), I get my `alert` as expected.

If I fill out all of the required elements, it pulls up the print dialouge as expected.

However, if I leave some of the boxes blank while others are correctly filled, it still goes to print instead of giving me the `alert` like I need. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code have to be rewritten, or better replace it with any validation plug-in.

But in your case, I suppose, you just forgot to return, in case you found some not filled field. So if you have any filled input it override your *validation* variable.

The simplest solution is to remove
`else {validation = true;}` code blocks, and add

```
validation = true;
```

at the beggining of the function.